# Can I change my hive external table storage format without affecting its partitions?

Tags: hadoop

I want to change my external table storage format from text file to ORC file. I already added partitions around 500 for the external table stored as 'TEXTFILE'. If I simply create another external table with 'ORC file' format, then i have to create all those partitions.

Instead Is it possible for me to change the storage format to ORC file without affecting the existing partitions for my table.

Comment: Hmmm....I'm confused here.  Are you talking about a database? On what system?   If so which?  Also, there is a DBA SE group that might be more applicable for your question.

Comment: I working on azure hd insight. And trying to do this in hive.